# how to compare two xml files with xslt?

Tags: linux, xslt

hello experts
I have 2 XML files, for ex:

```
<college>
    <student>
        <name>amit</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/final.c</file>
        <rollno>22</rollno>
        <function>a()</function>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>sumit</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/up.h</file>
        <rollno>23</rollno>
        <function>b()</function>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>nikhil</name>
        <file>/xyz/up.cpp</file>
        <rollno>24</rollno>
        <function>c()</function>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>bharat</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/down.h</file>
        <rollno>25</rollno>
        <function>d()</function>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>ajay</name>
        <file>/simple/st.h</file>
        <rollno>27</rollno>
        <function>e()</function>
    </student>
</college>
```

2nd XML file

```
<college>
    <student>
        <name>amit</name>
        <file>/abc/kk/final.c</file>
        <function>a()</function>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>nikhil</name>
        <file>/xyz/up.cpp</file>
        <function>c()</function>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>ajay</name>
        <file>/simple/st.h</file>
        <function>e()</function>
    </student>
</college>
```

I want to compare the two XML files such that, we will get the output of those nodes which are not common. As I am new to xslt please provide me the solution.
I am using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('1.xml')/college/student[
                         starts-with(file, '/abc/kk')
                      ]">
    <xsl:for-each select="document('2.xml')/college/student">
        <xsl:if test="string(document('1.xml')/college/student/function)
                   != string(document('2.xml')/college/student/function)">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of
                     select="document('1.xml')/college/student/name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of
                     select="document('1.xml')/college/student/file"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of
                     select="document('1.xml')/college/student/function"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You want nodes with distinct string value. There are a lot of question about the matter here in SO. Some even posted input samples!

Comment: This is an example of a BAD question -- there must be two XML documents provided. I have voted to `C L O S E ` this question. Please edit it and improve significantly!

Answer (score 0):

Use XSLT to transform the two XML files into two plain text files that contain just the informations you want to compare.

Then just `diff` the two plain text lists.

Don't forget to `sort` the lists before comparing with `diff`.

Comment: thanks for the reply...but can i do this on .xsl file without converting into text. i am using two for loops(for-each) in xsl file, and then checking the conditions using "if" , but not getting the result ..plz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You want just this XPath expression:

```
document('1.xml')/college/student[
   starts-with(file, '/abc/kk')
][
   not(
      function = document('2.xml')/college/student/function
   )
]
```

As proof, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates
             select="college/student[
                        starts-with(file, '/abc/kk')
                     ][
                        not(
                           function=document('2.xml')/college/student/function
                        )
                     ]"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="student">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="student/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>sumit</td>
        <td>/abc/kk/up.h</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>b()</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bharat</td>
        <td>/abc/kk/down.h</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>d()</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```